# How to alert json array values in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Can someone help me to alert below mentioned `getJSON` value?

**Script:**

```
//get char values  
$.getJSON(base_url + "index.php/admin/admin_controller/getjson_stock_data", function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    if(result.auth==="apparel"){
       alert(result.val);
    }
});
```

**JSON response:**

```
{auth: "apparel", val: Array(1)}
auth
:
"apparel"
val
:
Array(1)
0
:
{COUNT(ITEM_CAT): "3"}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
```

When I do the alert the results comes as `[object Object]`.Please help me to alert the value 3.

Comment: `result.val` is an Entire Array. `result.val[2]` is the third Array element. I would avoid using `alert()`.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't use `alert()` for debugging; it coerces types. USe `console.log()` instead

Answer (score 2):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(result.val[0]["COUNT(ITEM_CAT)"]))
```

Comment: your code gives me the result [{"COUNT(ITEM_CAT)":"3"}]. But I only need value 3. @zabusa

Comment: @EshanGurusinghe modified answer .

Comment: thank you very much @zabusa, But still a little question there console.log results give me "3". However I need 3 only without double quotes.

Comment: @EshanGurusinghe for debugging never use alert.use console.log().its the proper way.or use `debugger;`

Answer (score 1):

use JSON.stringify function.

```
$.getJSON(base_url + "index.php/admin/admin_controller/getjson_stock_data", function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    if(result.auth==="apparel"){
                       alert(JSON.stringify(result.val));
                       //alert(result.val);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You try like  this

```
 var responseAjax = JSON.parse(result);
 alert(responseAjax['val'].COUNT(ITEM_CAT));`
```

or

```
$.each(responseAjax['val'],function(i,v){
alert(v.COUNT(ITEM_CAT));    ` 
});`
```